# Iptables: how to allow forwarding from wireguard NIC only to some IP

Tags: iptables, wireguard, ip-forwarding

### Context

I successfully integrated **Wireguard** in my LAN so I could access my NAS (192.168.1.45) from the outside.

```
|Router|     ===:5182=> |VPN server|        ====> |NAS|
192.168.1.254           192.168.1.21 (wlan0)      192.168.1.45
                        10.10.10.1 (wg0)
```

Packets forwarding through my VPN server relies on:

1. ip forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf` (Cf [my script](https://github.com/zar3bski/server_scripts/blob/master/src/wireguard.sh#L58))
2. the following rules added (**-A**) when wireguard interface (**wg0**) is up.

```sh
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $main_nic -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $main_nic -j MASQUERADE
```

(this is the command wireguard execute when I stop **wg0**)

```sh
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o $main_nic -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o $main_nic -j MASQUERADE
```

### Need

This works like a charm but how could I restrict things so a client entering my LAN trough this VPN entrypoint could only access 192.168.1.45 and no other IP? Is it compatible with **ip forwarding**?

Ideally, if this could be entirely managed in the **PostUp** **PostDown** wireguard's directives (independently of the previous rules on the system), this would be amazing . Tried some but, let's face it, I am more of a developer than a network administrator

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, instead of arbitrarily allowing traffic, just make sure it goes to the destination IP you expect:

```
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -d 192.168.1.45 -j ACCEPT
```

As a side note, I wouldn't add and remove rules in the `PostUp` and `PostDown` hooks, it isn't useful to remove them when the interface no longer exists as they don't do anything in that case. Just leave them there all the time, it's less error-prone and easier to manage.